# Dark Black & Opaque UIToolbar

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitoolbar, uicolor

I am trying to create a UIToolbar which is dark black (real black as opposed to UIToolbar's "black"), that is slightly transparent or opaque. Below is a screenshot of the exact colour/opacity that I want it to be. Its the black overlay on top of the burger image.

I tried setting the colour, setting alpha, opaque property, translucent and nothing is working. Any suggestions?

[image: Toolbar needed]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make a png that is the color and opacity you want, add it to your project, and [myToolbar setBackgroundImage:thatImage];

Oops actually I think the method is setBackgroundImage:forToolbarPosition:barMetrics:

Comment: If its just a solid black color you want, you can make the image a 1x1 black pixel and then make the image stretchable.